# Read (any) characteristic value of a Bluetooth LE (Smart) device in python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I would like to read a characteristic value of a Bluetooth Low Energy (Smart). I don't want to use `gatttool` or `btgatt-client`. `d-bus` also isn't helpful. I want to do this in Python. I couldn't find any examples in the following:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/757380/bluetooth_essentials_for_programmers.4272206415.pdf
https://github.com/karulis/pybluez

nor is there any documentation on this on official `Python` site.

Ideally, I would just like to connect to `L2CAP` and get the attributes from there or to connect to `GATT` directly. Is this even possible?

Comment: You should be able to get stuff from `bluez` daemon over `D-Bus`. The latter has command line tools and Python bindings. It's not too easy though, good luck!

Comment: Added information, that ```dbus``` didn't help me

Comment: Well you can always open a socket to bluez and talk to it directly.

Comment: What do you mean open socket to ```bluez```? Open the socket to ```bluetoothd```?

Comment: What do you mean dbus didn't help you? Do you mean you couldn't get it to work (in which case someone can help you with that) or you don't want to use the dbus interface for other reasons? Also, AFAIK, pybluez has not been updated to support bluez5 nor does it explicitly support gatt.

Comment: dbus didn't help me in reading characteristic's value. It is limited in it's use and also not all of the characteristics are visible in dbus

Comment: You may be looking at an old version of bluez. The bluez devs have been working on the gatt dbus api for a while. It's now complete as of 5.29. Have a look at the bluez.org main page. And here's the gatt dbus api doc: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Comment: Yes, it's not working. I have the latest master of bluez and it's not fully functional. I also have been talking to the devs and they say that the dbus capabilities are limited.

Answer (score 0):

I have done simple scan, connect, gatt read/write, subscribe with [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy).

Maybe it doesn't look very "pythonish" but it's definitely worth to try.